# mySQL JOIN LEFT not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables: **tweets** (a.o. containing column tweet_id) and **references** (containing columns tweet_id and class_id). Not all tweets might have been assigned a class_id yet. I was expecting this to work to extract all information of a tweet inclusing its class_id (if it has been set):

```
SELECT t.*, r.class_id FROM tweets t 
LEFT JOIN references r ON (t.tweet_id = r.tweet_id) 
ORDER BY t.tweet_id DESC LIMIT 50
```

However, I keep getting an error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references r ON 
(t.tweet_id = r.tweet_id) ORDER BY t.tweet_id DESC LIMIT 50' at line 1
```

I don't understand where the error is coming from. I have build the query according to the MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) but I am probably missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT t.*, r.class_id FROM tweets t 
LEFT JOIN `references` r ON (t.tweet_id = r.tweet_id) 
ORDER BY t.tweet_id DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

`References` is a reserved word, so it must be enclosed with backticks.
Take a look at [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) to have a list of all reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

`REFERENCES` is an SQL reserved word, so you need to use quotes :

```
SELECT t.*, r.class_id FROM tweets t 
LEFT JOIN `references` r ON ...
```

By the way, SO colors your `references` word in blue, this should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

references is a reserved word of MySQL